# Configuring swagger-ui with server variable using configuration bean

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

In my spring boot project, I have an openapi3 yaml definition of API used by swagger UI. **I need to be able to dynamically change a part of server URL** while using the UI and I was able to configure it in yaml

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: Foo Service
  version: v1.0
servers:
  - url: https://{foo}.com
    variables:
      foo:
        default: bar
```

which makes the UI look like that
[image: swagger UI with server variable]

Now, I'd like to stop using yamls to define my API and use annotations and configuration beans instead. I feel like the way to go would be to set `servers` field in `io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI` bean, however I have no idea what to do considering I want the URL to be dynamically changed by the swagger UI.

Any guidance will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Let`s try that one,
I found that code from [github](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/124#issuecomment-546034557)

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.servers.Server;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.servers.ServerVariable;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.servers.ServerVariables;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class OpenApiGeneratorConfig {

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI defineOpenApi() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .info(defineInfo())
                .components(defineComponents())
                .addServersItem(defineServers());
    }

...

    private Server defineServers() {
        return new Server().url("http://{IP_Address}:8080/my-app")
                           .description("My APP REST API Server")
                           .variables(
                                   new ServerVariables().addServerVariable("IP_Address", new ServerVariable()
                                           //._default("www.example.com")
                                           ._default("localhost")
                                           .description("IP address of My APP REST API Server")
                                   )
                           );
    }
}
```